# BroadcastReceiver lifecycle

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-lifecycle

1) I have an Activity. This Activity starts a service, which in turn creates and registers a BroadcastReceiver.

2) I have an Activity. This Activity creates and registers a BroadcastReceiver.

When does BroadcastReceiver's life end in each of the above cases? In other words - when it gets destroyed and won't listen to broadcasts anymore?

Answer (score 6):

Declare broadcast receiver in manifest to achieve independent life cycle for it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, it cleared it somewhat but I'm still not sure how to achieve my goal: my Activity is used only to register a BroadcastReceiver. I want this receiver to be active after user exits the Activity - until I explicitly unregister it.

Comment: @rincEwind : **" I want this receiver to be active after user exits the Activity - until I explicitly unregister it."** - In that case use method 1. in your question. You should never register a receiver in an `Activity` and exit the `Activity` without first unregistering it. Register it in a `Service` but make sure the `Service` also unregisters it before it finishes (if/when it finishes). Don't leave orphaned objects hanging about.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Only onReceive() method is called in BroadcastReciver's life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

A BroadcastReciever life cycle ends (ie stop receiving broadcast) when you unregister it. usually you would do this in the onPause/onStop method. but it's up to you technically.

Example:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  // Register mMessageReceiver to receive messages.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("my-event"));
}

// handler for received Intents for the "my-event" event 
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Extract data included in the Intent
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
  }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  // Unregister since the activity is not visible
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: So what's the consequence of _not_ unregistering the broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 0):

The broadcst receiver component is active while the resi method is running, which listens to what you send to it and it is recommended to disable receiver registration when it is not needed. You can do this in the lifecycle methods of your components.

In the 1st case you should onDestroy call the unregisterReceiver(receiver) method
In the second case in the onPause\onStop\onDestroy method.